# htaccess rewrite url to insert .php extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my URL with a .htaccess file.

If I have a URL like:

`/test/controller/hello`

I want to rewrite it to:

`/test/controller.php/hello`

and I also want to add an `RewriteCond` to say that only
`(hello|hey|hi)` 
are allowed when it's none of those 3 I want it to be
hello .

My condition for the 3 possibilities is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/controller/(hey|hello|hi)$
RewriteRule . ^/test/controller/hello$
```

is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(hey|hello|hi)$
RewriteRule ^test/([^/.]+)/(.+)$ /test/$1.php/$2 [NC,L]
```

The condition tests if **hey** or **hello** or **hi** is at the end of the uri. If the conditon is true then the rule rewrites **test/foo/hello|hi|hey** to **test/foo.php/hello|hi|hey** .